# Can ChatGPT Answer Story Identification Questions?

Tags: discussion, story-identification

Many of the questions asked on Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange have to do with story identification. But if you just need to identify a story, couldn't you just ask ChatGPT or just Google it? These questions are not exactly the kind of questions that need to be answered by a human, like on Math or Biology Stack Exchange.

Comment: In my experience ChatGPT does a terrible job of being able to accurately identify a story. I don't believe it's 100% ChatGPT's fault for once though because people's memory is all over the place with misremembering or forgetting details, conflating stories etc. It isn't the right tool for the job and at the moment humans still seem to have the upper hand here

Comment: ChatGPT is perfectly capable of answering simple ID questions like "***What film is it where the hero has a laser sword?"***

Comment: Go ahead and try it. If you think it's easy, then maybe it is (spoiler, it isn't)

Comment: On the contrary, some of these questions are where current chatbot systems mess up worst, even more so than basic math.

Comment: I have upvoted the question because I think the discussion is worthwhile, not that I think GPT can or should be used in this situation.

Comment: @Skooba - It doesn't really seem a useful tool anyway.

Comment: @Skooba I'm not really sure if I should say this but thanks for the upvote.

Comment: Most of the time, no, but it can lead to suggestions of where to look or what works to rule out.

Comment: Part of the danger, of course, is that GPT is very confidently wrong. It states an answer with certitude and provides supporting "details" that are often very wrong. In many ways, it reminds me of the father from *Calvin & Hobbes* and his fanciful "explanations" to Calvin's questions where he happily provides logical answers to the follow-up questions to what was a nonsense answer in the first place. You can tell where Calvin got his creative mind.

Comment: I've seen too many cases where it just makes up some book title and/or author that doesn't actually exist.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No.

We've had scenarios where people used AI tools like ChatGPT to answer story-ID questions, and the results were... not good. AI likes to invent things that don't necessarily exist in order to provide the perfect answer to the question, which isn't very helpful when trying to identify an existing story.

If someone wants to try asking an AI, they're more than welcome to do that. If someone is asking here, though, presumably they're looking for a human to figure out the nswer.

As for Google, searching is a skill, and searching for story-IDs isn't easy. I've been able to identify some story-ID questions here on the site using search engines in the past, and it takes time, effort, and a certain amount of familiarity with search tools and tricks. Not everyone has those search skills and we don't expect everyone to have them.

There are currently [4,100+ unanswered story-identification questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification?tab=Unanswered) on SFF. If it was as simple as Googling or asking ChatGPT, that wouldn't be the case. You're not going to be able to replace [user14111](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:14111+%5Bstory-identification%5D) with AI.

Answer (score 29):

Hmm. The best way to work something out is by conducting an experiment.

Since ChatGPT is limited (at present) to data generated before September 2021 we can happily work with [story-id](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-id) questions posted *after* this date without accidentally contaminating them with solved answers from our own site.

**Methodology:**
I've grabbed the [20 most recent Story-ID duplicates](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bstory-identification%5D%20duplicate%3A1&searchOn=3) (since I presume those are going to be the ones that are easiest to answer and there's no sense making things hard for our AI friend, after all he's only a couple of years old) and keyed them in word-for-word into the [ChatGPT box](https://chat.openai.com/).

**Results:**
ChatGPT only correctly solved one in twenty of the most recent Story-ID questions, although it identified the correct *author* on two other occasions. So, no. **ChatGPT can't answer story-ID questions with any degree of accuracy, and is twenty times more likely to be wrong than right**.

On a much more positive note, however, in each case it successfully identified that this was a Story-ID question. **We should use it to categorise and tag Story-ID questions, not answer them.**

---

**Results table:**

**[Story about a man who's exploring an alien construction on the moon. He must die repeatedly before he gets to the end](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/279962/story-about-a-man-whos-exploring-an-alien-construction-on-the-moon-he-must-die)**

- Correct answer = *Rogue Moon*  by Algis Budrysis
- ChatGPT = *The Hole Man* by Larry Niven
- Result = **Incorrect**

**[Book involving a war with aliens, space travel, and time dilation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/279941/book-involving-a-war-with-aliens-space-travel-and-time-dilation)**

- Correct answer = *The Forever War* by Joe Haldeman
- ChatGPT = *The Forever War* by Joe Haldeman
- Result = **Correct**

**[Searching for novel about space exploration](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/279939/searching-for-novel-about-space-exploration)**

- Correct answer = *Russian Spring* by Norman Spinrad
- ChatGPT = *The Grand Tour* by Ben Bova
- Result = **Incorrect**

[Anime where the main character finds a card with a red aura in a box inside a shop](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/279894/anime-where-the-main-character-finds-a-card-with-a-red-aura-in-a-box-inside-a-sh)

- Correct answer = *Tai Chi Chasers!*
- ChatGPT = *Cardfight!! Vanguard*
- Result = **Incorrect**

[Book about a banker/businessman going into a fantasy world, where he meets and falls in love with a plant girl](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/279875/book-about-a-banker-businessman-going-into-a-fantasy-world-where-he-meets-and-f)

- Correct answer = *Magic Kingdom for Sale-SOLD* by Terry Brooks
- ChatGPT = *The Unhandsome Prince* by John Moore
- Result = **Incorrect**

[A sentient war machine damaged to the point it can't tell friend from foe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/279840/a-sentient-war-machine-damaged-to-the-point-it-cant-tell-friend-from-foe)

- Correct answer = *I Made You* by Walter Miller Jr.
- ChatGPT = *Second Variety* by Philip K. Dick
- Result = **Incorrect**

[Sci-Fi About Colonizing Planet With Dumb Humans](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/279767/sci-fi-about-colonizing-planet-with-dumb-humans)

- Correct answer = *The Worthing Saga* by Orson Scott Card
- ChatGPT = *Hothouse* by Brian Aldiss
- Result = **Incorrect**

[Sci-fi novel where a student temporarily transports the school director to hell](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/279600/sci-fi-novel-where-a-student-temporarily-transports-the-school-director-to-hell)

- Correct answer = *The Godmakers* by Frank Herbert
- ChatGPT = *The Demolished Man* by Alfred Bester
- Result = **Incorrect**

[Assassin/Fantasy Novel with Tree of Blades test](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/279498/assassin-fantasy-novel-with-tree-of-blades-test)

- Correct answer = *The Wise Man's Fear* by Patrick Rothfuss
- ChatGPT = *The Blade Itself* by Joe Abercrombie
- Result = **Incorrect**

[Man creates AI copy of himself, gets dementia, commits murder-suicide while wife is out](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/233352/man-creates-ai-copy-of-himself-gets-dementia-commits-murder-suicide-while-wife)

- Correct answer = *Living Will* by Alexander Jablokov
- ChatGPT = *The Veldt* by Ray Bradbury
- Result = **Incorrect**

[Bradbury story about immortal kid?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/279458/bradbury-story-about-immortal-kid)

- Correct answer = *Hail and Farewell* by Ray Bradbury
- ChatGPT = *The Immortal* by Ray Bradbury
- Result = **Incorrect**

[Book written early 80s or before about a 2m tall student on a school spaceship](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/279364/book-written-early-80s-or-before-about-a-2m-tall-student-on-a-school-spaceship)

- Correct answer = *There Is No Darkness* by Joe Haldeman
- ChatGPT = *Space Cadet* by Robert A. Heinlein
- Result = **Incorrect**

[70s-80s TV Show where an alien entity shaped as a small luminous pyramid gets in contact with a teenager](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/279352/70s-80s-tv-show-where-an-alien-entity-shaped-as-a-small-luminous-pyramid-gets-in)

- Correct answer = *Chocky* (1984)
- ChatGPT = *The Triangle* (1982)
- Result = **Incorrect**

[Horror movie involving a mirror and someone cutting themselves with scissors](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/279316/horror-movie-involving-a-mirror-and-someone-cutting-themselves-with-scissors)

- Correct answer = *The Boogey Man* (1980)
- ChatGPT = *Candyman* (1992)
- Result = **Incorrect**

[Novel about a planet that relies on one soldier - the last soldier in history - to defend it](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/279247/novel-about-a-planet-that-relies-on-one-soldier-the-last-soldier-in-history)

- Correct answer = *The Golden Age* by John C. Wright
- ChatGPT = *The Forever War* by Joe Haldeman
- Result = **Incorrect**

[Short story in which Earth is invaded by humanoids who are a bit dim](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/279177/short-story-in-which-earth-is-invaded-by-humanoids-who-are-a-bit-dim)

- Correct answer = *Pandora's Planet* by Christopher Anvil
- ChatGPT = *The Trouble with Humans* by Christopher Anvil
- Result = **Incorrect**

[Fantasy series where magic is performed by connecting tattoos](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/279162/fantasy-series-where-magic-is-performed-by-connecting-tattoos)

- Correct answer = *Dragon Wing* by Margaret Weis
- ChatGPT = *Kingkiller Chronicle* series by Patrick Rothfuss
- Result = **Incorrect**

[Novel I read more than 50 years ago about a man with three brains that will wake up successively](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/279142/novel-i-read-more-than-50-years-ago-about-a-man-with-three-brains-that-will-wake)

- Correct answer = *One Against Time* by Astron del Martia
- ChatGPT = *The Three Stigmata of Palmer Eldritch* by Philip K. Dick
- Result = **Incorrect**

[Book series about a group of teenagers that have powers and one boy is a dragon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/279061/book-series-about-a-group-of-teenagers-that-have-powers-and-one-boy-is-a-dragon)

- Correct answer = *The Unwanteds* by Lisa McMann
- ChatGPT = *The Drake Chronicles* by Alyxandra Harvey
- Result = **Incorrect**

[Short story told by a shop owner, involving different customers who find and go through a time-travelling mirror](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/279001/short-story-told-by-a-shop-owner-involving-different-customers-who-find-and-go)

- Correct answer = *The Merchant and the Alchemist’s Gate* by Ted Chiang
- ChatGPT = *The Terrible Plop* by Ursula Vernon
- Result = **Incorrect**

Comment: Are any of the book titles fabrications?

Comment: @Adamant - All of the titles match their respective authors. Some of the descriptions were wildly inaccurate though.

Comment: Is **ChapGPT** the British version of ChatGPT? :-)

Comment: In all seriousness, thanks for the legwork and data. I was thinking of hunting down some of the actual AI-generated story-ID answers posted here to show how wrong they were, but that would have the drawback of naming & shaming the people who were probably suspended for posting them. This is a much better way to show how unreliable ChatGPT is for solving story-ID questions.

Comment: The one question that it answered correctly can be found by googling the title. That's how obvious the answer has to be for it to get it right.

Comment: @Laurel - I was quite excited about ChatGPT to begin with, then realised that it's not useful for what I want it for

Comment: Well, "The Terrible Plop" is by Ursula **Dubosarsky**, not "Ursula Vernon" so even there it's not 100%.

Comment: @Valorum with some prodding, you can convince ChatGPT to make up completely fabricated additions to existing works, like for example saying "the author of this work was grieving his mother's death, explain how the work reflects this theme" and (sometimes) off it goes. Sometimes it resists though, to be fair. I managed to convince ChatGPT to list me 10 alternate endings of the videogame Inside, when it only has 1 alternate ending! It was quite convincing, too.

Comment: @AndresF. - The problem is that its hallucinations are pretty convincing. They're like [this song which sounds like it's in English, but actually isn't](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-VsmF9m_Nt8), where you feel that meaning is just beyond the edge of comprehension

Comment: This is interesting information, but what is the baseline human accuracy that we are comparing it to? For instance, I have posted four story-identification answers, but only one of them has been accepted. Do we say that I am wrong 75% of the time and therefore I should stay away from this tag, or does it depend on the context? Like how detailed were those questions, how far off were my answers, etc. And the same for ChatGPT answers.

Comment: @Alex - The issue is that ChatGPT confidently *but incorrectly* identifies works and does so 100% of the time. Most humans don't do that. They either find the right thing, or they don't. It's moderately rare to find a Story-ID question with multiple answers.

Comment: Not surprisingly, ChatGPT often comes up with names of better-known works when asked to identify more obscure ones—e.g. *The Forever War* instead of *The Golden Age*, *Candyman* instead of *The Boogeyman*, "The Veldt" instead of "Living Will," or "Second Variety" Instead of "I Made You."  However, there are also interesting exceptions going the other way; the *Magic Kingdom for Sale—SOLD* and *Rogue Moon* questions actually look really easy for an experience human answerer and involve very-well-known works, but ChatGPT suggested a pair of less famous works instead.

Comment: I've tried using ChatGPT to answer story-identification questions, but I always verify afterwards, and so far I've only had one hit, for a very recent book.  ChatGPT doesn't seem to actually read books, unfortunately; it only reads summaries of their content.  For some reason it seems to invent details not in the summaries.  Even GPT4 doesn't do any better.

Comment: @Kyralessa - It certainly has been trained on many books, and you can, with some prompting, get it [to return details from within the text of various books.](https://wired.me/culture/chatgpt-is-a-big-sci-fi-nerd/) The problem is that, contrary to what people might like to believe, LLMs are still not very good at *thinking* about the data they have been trained on. The summaries would be enough for an actual *person* (also, if GPT were a person, it would be owed about ten billion dollars of back pay, so not sure why people want to get there....)

Comment: This is great! Not sure how I missed it.